# Azure function does not access to Azure files share

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to read a file from shared file from an Azure function.
All works fine in local, but I'm getting "connectionString" error when I deploy my test project. The code is very simply:

```
 string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyStorage", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        string FileSharedContainer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MySharedContainer", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        string InputCloudFolder = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("InputCloudFolder", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        string ProcessedCloudFolder = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProcessedCloudFolder", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        CloudFileClient cloudFileClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
        CloudFileShare cloudFileShare = cloudFileClient.GetShareReference(FileSharedContainer);
        CloudFileDirectory rootDirectory = cloudFileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
        CloudFileDirectory InputfileDirectory = rootDirectory.GetDirectoryReference(InputCloudFolder);
        CloudFileDirectory ProcessedfileDirectory = rootDirectory.GetDirectoryReference(ProcessedCloudFolder);
        List<IListFileItem> fileList = GetAllFilesFromDirectory(InputfileDirectory);
        string fileNames = "";
        foreach (var p in fileList)
        {
            var CurrentFile = (CloudFile)p;
            fileNames += CurrentFile.Name +" ";
        }
        return new OkObjectResult("N. File processed is: " + fileList.Count + ".  Filenames" + fileNames);
```

It's a demo http trigger function that returns a file list from a shared files folder even on Azure.
It works perfectly on local machine but it fails on deploy environment with this error:

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Please help me....!

Comment: Have you added the MyStorage connection string in the App configuration? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal. Can you put a debug print statement to check if your code is actually retrieving that value? And any specific reason why you are using the V11 legacy version of the SDK? See https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Files.Shares/ for the new V12 version.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Anupam Chand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14358677/anupam-chand). Posting your suggestion as an answer so that it will be helpful for other community members who face similar kind of issues.

As Suggested have you added the mystorage connection string as per the below  image

[image]

Also try to debug the statement to check the code retrieving the value. and try to use new version of SDK.

```
dotnet add package Azure.Storage.Files.Shares
```

For further information check the [My Storage application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal) and [NuGet Packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Files.Shares/)